# Opening google-chrome from commandline with a specific window size

Tags: command-line, bash, google-chrome

When I run the following command:

`nohup google-chrome-stable --incognito --window-size="770,570" index.html /dev/null &`

it works when there is no chrome window opened already.
Otherwise it opens with the same window size as the old one.

How can I fix this?

I wrote a function in my bashrc so that I can create an html directory and edit the files inside effciently. The code is part of that function.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and the version of bash thereof.

Comment: You also mean that the file opens in the window that is already open? If so, that is important information that should be in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `--new-window`:

```bsh
nohup google-chrome-stable --incognito --window-size="770,570" index.html /dev/null ----new-window &
```